# Spark Dataframe sorting not working on clustered environment in Spark 1.6

Tags: sorting, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

We are facing certain challenges in sorting of data on dataframes in Spark 1.6 on clustered environment . We are using `df.orderBy(userColumn, rankColumn)`. The sorting of data is proper when the data is in one partition. As soon as the partition size increases , the dataframe sorting is not working on clustered environment. We tried Distribute by and sort by approach as well as per the below post: http://saurzcode.in/2015/01/hive-sort-vs-order-vs-distribute-vs-cluster/. This is also not working. Please suggest.

Comment: what is your input? what have you done? what is the expected output? what is the actual output?

Comment: Input: 
df.show()
userColumn rankColumn
U5 5
U6 1
U1 1
U1 2
U5 4
U5 2
U2 4
U3 1  

df = df.orderBy(userColumn, rankColumn)
df.show()
Expected Output:
userColumn rankColumn
U1 1
U1 2
U2 4
U3 1
U5 2
U5 4
U5 5
U6 1

Actual Output(if spark puts all data in one parition):
userColumn rankColumn
U1 1
U1 2
U2 4
U3 1
U5 2
U5 4
U5 5
U6 1

Actual Output(if spark does not put all data in one parition):
U1 2
U1 1
U3 1
U2 4
U6 1
U5 2
U5 4
U5 5

Comment: @Yaron : Please let me know if you need any more details.